# Converting height in python: commas for feet and inches giving me a rough time

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

So I'm working on a homework assignment dealing with converting height of a group of people form feet' and inches" to meters, and then averaging the entire groups height.

Everything in my code works fine, other than the input of feet and inches. Here's the entire code:

```
def heights():
    conversion = .0254
    group = int(input('How many people are in your group? '))

    for people in range(1, group+1):
        print('\n''Person Number', people)
        feet = range(10)
        inches = range(12)
        a = int(input('Enter your height in feet inches, separated by a comma: '))
        meters = a*conversion
        print("Your height in feet and inches: ", a,"'",'"')
        print("Your height in meters is: ", meters)

    print('\n' "The average height of your group in feet and inches is: ", a/group)
    print("The average height of your group in meters is: ", a/meters)
```

So for line 8 where it a = starts,
if the user inputs their height lets say: 6,2.   my program crashes
but if you do just 74, as if all in inches, the code runs smoothly and does it fine.
any tips on how I can get this to work? I tried adding a `.split(',')` function but that only crashed it again. it basically has to look like:

Enter your height in feet and inches: 6, 2
your height in feet and inches is 6' 2"
your height in meters is 1.87

I added the feet = range thinking something like that would work, as of now, it does nothing in my code, it's mostly there so i don't forget while i play around and try to figure it out

Comment: Please indent your function.

Comment: @pp_, I think i did that now, sorry, i'm new and still figuring the site out

Comment: It's finde, I made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle string input of '6, 2' (for example), you do need to parse the string. One approach is - as you mention - splitting the string on the comma. After that, you'll have a list of the string components: ['6', '2']
You can then access each component (item in the list) by indexing. The relevant bits are:

```
height = a.split(',')
feet = int(height[0])
inches = int(height[1])
```

Then you can calculate total inches (feet*12 + inches), convert to meters, average, etc.

The error that you get (in your comment, below) is because you are trying to convert the input string to an int (in your statement `int(input(...` ), but the string '6,2' can't be converted to an integer, hence the error. First, you have to separate the pieces of it and then do the conversion, as in the snippet above.

To do the conversion, you want to calculate total inches and then convert to metric. So following from the snippet above:

```
tot_inches = feet*12 + inches
meters = tot_inches * 0.0254
```

As for `input` vs `raw_input`, it would help to know which version of Python you're using, as `raw_input` is a 2.X feature (not usable in 3.X).

Finally, for dealing with the averages, you'll need to keep a running total of all the entered heights. For example, near the start of your function, initialize a variable `tot_inches = 0`, then after each input, increase the `tot_inches` like this:

```
tot_inches = tot_inches + (12*feet + inches)
```

Then, when calculating average height, you can do `tot_inches/group`, which would be average height in inches, which you can then convert to feet and inches. Putting it all together:

```
def heights():
conversion = .0254
group = int(input('How many people are in your group? '))

# initialize running total
tot_inches = 0

for people in range(1, group+1):
    print('\n''Person Number', people)

    a = input('Enter your height in feet inches, separated by a comma: ')
    height = a.split(',')
    feet = int(height[0])
    inches = int(height[1])
    meters = (12*feet + inches)*0.0254
    tot_inches += (12*feet + inches)
    print ("Your height in feet and inches: ", feet,"'", inches,'"')

    print ("Your height in meters is: ", meters)

print('\n' "The average height of your group in inches is: ", tot_inches/group)
print ('The average height in feet and inches is: ', tot_inches/(group*12), (tot_inches/group)%12
print("The average height of your group in meters is: ", (tot_inches*0.0254)/group)
```

Comment: Trying to figure out how to paste a code in a comment. sorry, one minute

With this approach i added it like this:
`for people in range(1, group+1):
        print('\n''Person Number', people)
        a = int(input('Enter your height in feet inches, separated by a comma: '))
        height = a.split(',')
        feet = int(height[0])
        inches = int(height[1])
        meters = a*conversion
        print("Your height in feet and inches: ", a,"'",'"')
        print("Your height in meters is: ", meters)`

But then i get the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6, 2'

Comment: I'm using python 3 so i learned thats why it won't work. raw_input is just input now.

back to the issue though, i added the edit you made to my program to see what would happen and i keep getting the same error `    height = a.split(',')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

anytime i try to use split, i always get an error in any program and i'm not sure why. IT seems to only work when i say something like name = stidgeon

print(name.split('dg'). basic things like that..

Comment: also, a tuple is just ( ) with something in there correct?

Comment: tuple is an immutable sequence of format (1,2,3 . . .) read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm or https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 0):

When you enter values separated by a comma, `input` will interpret it as a tuple.
So if input is `6`, the value of `a` will be integer `6`. But if the input is `6,2`, the value of `a` will be a tuple `(6, 2)`.

`input` will `eval`uate your expression.

Easier way is to use `raw_input`, which will simply take the input as a string.

```
a = raw_input('Enter your height in feet inches, separated by a comma: ').split(',')
a = [int(_) for _ in a]
```

Then you can check the length of array `a` to see if there was comma in the input.

---

Edit: for python3, simply replacing `raw_input` by `input` in the above code should work.
What error are you getting if you do so?

Comment: Is there a reason I can't have it as a = raw_input('Enter ...')?
I put that into my code, and it crashes once it gets to that line because raw_input doesn't change colors and let me write anything

Comment: Simply using `a = raw_input('Enter ...')` shouldn't cause any trouble. Can you provide some more code?

Comment: Yes sorry, I assumed python 2 for no reason!

Comment: as of now, nothing dealing with split. i get this as the error-


`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6,2'` my code only works if i do it without the comma because of that. and i tried eval(input(....) but that doesnt work either

Comment: That seems to be because you are directly trying to convert the input into int, i.e. `int(input('...'))`. You need to call split, which will convert the input into a list of strings. Then you will have to convert the values in that list to int. (Do you still get an error if you use the above answer, using input instead of raw_input?)